# What are the Mass Effect 2 planet scan materials limits?

Tags: mass-effect-2

When [scanning planets for resources](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Planet_Scanning) (uh, it is obnoxious work — not fun!) there are indicators that fill up as you acquire more resources. (Eezo, Iridium, Platinum, Palladium)

Do these indicators show the maximum spare resources your ship can store? If so, how many resources is 100% on the indicator for each material? Or can you go over these limits? Or if you try to go over is the material wasted? If you go over this limit by picking up materials when not planet scanning (when down on a planet or space station), do you get credit rewards instead, like if you go over your Medi-gel limit?

[image: screenshot of scanning a planet in Mass Effect 2]

Comment: Dear Bioware: Please take out the mining tasks in ME3. The ME1 and ME2 systems felt like work, not fun.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The bars cap out at 25,000, but they don't represent a resource stockpile limit. You can continue to accrue rare materials long after the bar is filled.

I think I made it up to 70,000 units of Palladium, once.

Comment: I've stockpiled over 200,000 units on some of them my last play through, so the max limit must be extremely high.

Comment: The number's probably stored as an int, which, depending on the language (32-bit integers are common) could mean a limit of 4,294 967,296. (Or more!)

Comment: @RavenDreamer: That's an unsigned integer. Signed integers are 2,147,483,647

Comment: @Mufasa why would it need to be signed, though? You can't have negative resources!

Comment: @Raven Dreamer — Unless the value is expected to reach those levels, it is typical to leave `int`s as signed, even if values can't drop below 0.  I suspect this is a combination of laziness and integers defaulting to signed in most languages.  ;-)

Comment: @RavenDreamer: Yeah, Ben's right. Laziness often. Or, in some languages, like C# (.Net), making it unsigned is often more work than it is worth.

Comment: As a coder, no, I will not take ten seconds to make my ints signed just so that you can accumulate 10000 times the useful amount of minerals instead of "only" 5000 times.

Comment: Also...based on what I see there, no wonder Microsoft thought the *#$@ mining interface was acceptable. You PCers only had to move the mouse around a lot. Us consolers had to go up...and down...and up...and down...slowly, over and over again. Especially for those of us who were OCD.